# PHP: Documentation of function list

Tags: php

I have a file which consist of user defined functions with CamelCase names :

```
// some useful comments
function functionOne(){
   return false;
}

// some other useful comment
function addTwoNumbers($x,$y)
{
   return 5;
}
...
```

I would like to output these functions sorted by name like

```
addTwoNumbers($x,$y) 
2 parameters 
Comment: some other useful comment

functionOne() 
0 parameters 
Comment: some useful comments
```

So far, I get a list of function names like this:

```
include '../includes/functions.php';

$allFunctions = get_defined_functions();

$userFunctions = $allFunctions['user'];
sort($userFunctions);

foreach ($userFunctions as $functionName) {
  echo $functionName. "<br>";
}
```

My main problem is that I do not know how to display the number of parameters of each function and the parameter variable names.

Further (but I could live with it) the function names are only displayed with lower case letters, so I can't read them in CamelCase.

And finally the comments are of course not shown. I was thinking of writing them in an array `$comments['functionOne']="some useful comments"`.

So my main problem is how do you get the parameter variable names and number.

Comment: so, please don't make your function name camel case then. PHP is not Java.

Comment: As a start, check the [reflection api](https://secure.php.net/manual/book.reflection.php). But why would you want to do this? You could simply use [phpDocumentor](https://phpdoc.org/).

Comment: @Raptor I don't think that is enough reason to not use camelCase. Many modern frameworks and libraries like Zend Framework 2 and Symfony 2 use camelCase for method names. And I personally like it.

Comment: @Yoshi thank you! Looks awesome, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get paramater number and names, you can use [`Reflection`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) in PHP :

```
function getFunctionArgumentNames($functionName) {
    $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($functionName);
    $argumentNames= array();
    foreach ($reflection ->getParameters() as $parameter) {
        $argumentNames[] = $parameter->name;   
    }
    return $argumentNames;
}
```

Then you'll have your parameter names, and the length of the returned array will give you how many there are.

---

More information can be found about it :

- [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)
- [`ReflectionObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php)
- [What is Reflection in PHP ?](http://culttt.com/2014/07/02/reflection-php/)

  > Another common use of Reflection is for creating documentation. It would be extremely labour intensive to write documentation about every method of every class of a large framework or application. Instead, Reflection can automatically generate the documentation for you. It does this by inspecting each method, constructor and class to determine what goes in and what comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Use ReflectionFunction class

for example:

```
$refFunc = new ReflectionFunction('preg_replace');
foreach( $refFunc->getParameters() as $param ){
    print $param;
}
```

The ReflectionFunction class reports information about a function.
See more http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php